# How do I fix this preparedStatement error when returning a decimal value?

Tags: java, mysql, string, type-conversion, decimal

So I basically am returning an int value from a database as a string (don't ask why). Now, I have to compare it with some values I already have, however, there seems to be a discrepancy as to the values.

My value : 204.4
The database returned value : 204.40

Is there any way to remove the extra zero?

My code for reading is:

```
            if(resultSet.getString(i) != null) {
                rowOfData.add(resultSet.getString(i).trim());
            } else {
                rowOfData.add("");
            }
```

And for comparison is:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < inputRow.size(); i++) { 
        if(!tableRowData.contains(inputRow.get(i))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about treating it as an appropriate number?

```
String.valueOf(resultSet.getDouble(i))
```

If the value is returned *as* a String, then the trailing "0" never has a chance to be treated in a numeric context and "fall off".

When treated *as* a number the trailing 0 is insignificant and "falls off":

```
204.40 == 204.4        // -> true
String.valueOf(204.40) // -> "204.4"
```

Of course, it might be more appropriate to use the number instead of turning it [back] into a String ..

Comment: Why thanks! I totally could have never ever thought of that... How ingenious.

Comment: (If you're going to downvote - which is perfectly okay - please explain why so that I may learn, correct/annotate my answer, and prevent spreading incorrect information!)

Comment: Well, you know pretty well I cannot really do that right? Or I would not have this problem! Thanks anyway for your help though.

Comment: @gran_profaci Of course you can do it. The same principal applies - even if RS returns something that getDouble will choke on. While I'd urge fixing the RS there are other ways to fix up a String and turn it into a double (or other more appropriate number). Anyway, hope you solve your problem!